# How to write this in C# Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am not a pro on Linq but trying to understand. How to write this code (written in VB) in C#

> Dim x = From p in db.YourClass _
>
> Where p.fl1 = cn1 And p.f12 = cn2
>
> Select _
>
> sum1 = x.Sum(Function(y) y.fl1), _
>
> sum2 = x.Sum(Function(y) y.fl2), _
>
> sum3 = x.Sum(Function(y) y.fl3)

what i am trying to achieve is this,

> select sum(fl1),sum(fl2),sum(fl3)
>
> where fl1 =cn1 and fl2=cn2

[The above sample found here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataset/thread/0dee04b9-c08c-41fe-8e8a-471454ea661a/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var x = from p in db.YourClass 
        where p.fl1 == cn1 && p.f12 == cn2
        select p;

  var sum1 = x.Sum(y=>y.fl1), 

  var sum2 = x.Sum(y=>y.fl2), 

  var sum3 = x.Sum(y=>y.fl3)
```

**Edit:** In one query I think this can work fast:

```
var x = (from p in db.YourClass 

        select new 
        {
         s1 = db.YourClass.Where(y=> y.fl1 == cn1 && y.f12 == cn2).Sum(y=>y.fl1),
         s2 = db.YourClass.Where(y=> y.fl1 == cn1 && y.f12 == cn2).Sum(y=>y.fl2),
         s3 = db.YourClass.Where(y=> y.fl1 == cn1 && y.f12 == cn2).Sum(y=>y.fl3)
        }).First();

 int sum1 = x.s1, sum2 = x.s2, sum3 = x.s3;
```

Comment: How can you access x in the statement where it is just defined?

Comment: @Jan, edited, at first glance I think is `p` or something available.

Comment: but the issue with this is, if the table is huge then all the data would be retrieved based on the condition. I wanted to do the sum at the server side rather than retrieving all first and then do the sum.

Comment: @Dilberted, no I didn't execute code and I just return sum, x is not initialized and is just a query. In fact this called as deferred execution.

Comment: oh yes, u r right. i overlooked the "var x =", i should have thought about delayed execution :) but do u think it will still run 3 queries on the server to do the Sum. Am i right?

Comment: @Dilberted, It runs 3 query on server yes

Comment: atleast it helped upto some extent. but still unable to understand that in VB we can do the sum within the linq query but not in C#.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8104/discussion-between-saeed-amiri-and-dilberted)

Answer (score 4):

```
var x =
    from p in db.YourClass
    where p.fl1 == cn1 && p.fl2 == cn2
    select p;


var sum1 = x.Sum(y => t.fl1);
var sum2 = x.Sum(y => t.fl2);
var sum3 = x.Sum(y => t.fl3);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use lambda expression ,

```
public class Sums
{
   public int Sum1{get;set;}
   public int Sum2{get;set;}
   public int Sum3{get;set;}
}

var list = db.YourClass.Where(x=>x.fl1==cn1 && x.f12==cn2).Select(y => 
                                new Sums{ 
                                    Sum1 = y.Sum(z=>z.fl1),
                                    Sum2 = y.Sum(z=>z.fl2),
                                    Sum3 = y.Sum(z=>z.fl3)
                                }).ToList();
```

Comment: What is this? you will fetch all data.

Comment: from there is no function for Sum, as y will give out the properties of the database table.